# Disable /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile in sbt native packager rpm build

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec, sbt-native-packager

I have few python files which I copy inside rpm using sbt-native-packager

But right now rpm compiles them to pyo and pyc files which I do not want.

How to tell it to not to do that.

Thanks

Comment: can you post snippets of spec file, where you call `setup.py` in `%build` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the spec file, `%build` section where you call `setup.py`, you can use `--no-target-compile`. In some cases, `--no-compile` also works.

```
%build
python setup.py --no-compile
```